# Function for highlighting the path back to the root node

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to find a function that highlights the path from the following nodes:

a > b > c > d > a

The importance is highlighting the path back to 'a'.

Or even a function where you can predefine the route for the path.

Answer (score 0):

There are several [algorithms](http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/algorithms) that can be used for finding paths (e.g. BFS, A*, etc).

As for highlighting, you should define your [style](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style) appropriately -- probably with a `highlight` class or similar.